# open CMD window and run command

Tags: vbscript

The following VB script open CMD window and perform ping to IP – 127.0.0.1

I don’t understand why the output from the CMD window include only the results from ping and not also the “ping 127.0.0.1” ?

My question what need to change in my VB script in order to see also  the ping command from the CMD window and not only the ping results ?

My VB script:

```
 Dim oShell
 Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
 oShell.run "cmd /k CD C:\Program Files & ping 127.0.0.1   " ,1 , true
```

what I see from CMD is only that:  ( ping 127.0.0.1 not apears ? )

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: Why not just use a batch file?

Comment: I use already along cod of VB script so this option not relevant

Comment: You could use "cmd /k @echo ping 127.0.0.1 & ping 127.0.0.1". The CD is not needed (and actually does not work due to the space in the directory name).

Comment: not good I want the real command and not only to print the "ping 127.0.0.1" , I ask this because some times I run other command with args and they can stuck and I need to see this on CMD screen

Comment: This is exactly what should be expected. If you type 'ping 127.0.0.1` from an actual command prompt, the output doesn't repeat your `ping 127.0.0.1` again before it starts showing you the results. Why would you expect it to do so just because you ran it from VBScript?

Comment: What is the actual purpose of doing this? Why do you need the command to appear in the command prompt?

Comment: Purpose - sometimes values from parameters not appears from commands so I want to verify the values or arguments in command

Comment: Use `MsgBox` to display the command string before running it via `oShell.Run`.

Answer (score 1):

"ping 127.0.0.1" is a batch file command. If you hit the start button, type "command prompt", open up command prompt and type that command then you'll get an output along the lines of what I got.

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL-128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL-128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL-128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL-128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
     Packets: Sent = 4, Received =  4, lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```